# Pass onClick Value From One Component to Another in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, onclick

I have two components, one which handles the buttons and another which is the index of the page.

The index of the page is structured as follows

```
const MainComp = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState(' ')

    const test = [
        'One',
        'Two',
        'Three',
    ]

    return (
        <>
            <ChildComp onClick={() => test.map((i) => setText(i))} /> 
            {text}
        </>
    )
}
```

In the button component I have this...

```
const ChildComp = ({ onClick }) => {
    const test2 = [1,2,3]

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {test2.map((data) => (
                    <button onClick={onClick}>
                        {data}
                    </button>
                ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

I want the value of each item in `test` to show up when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
...
const test2 = [1, 2, 3]

const onClick = (item) => alert(item)

return (
  <>
    <div>
      {test2.map((data) => (
        <button onClick={() => onClick(data)}>{data}</button>
      ))}
    </div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: Sorry I meant I want the value of `test` not `test2`!

Comment: Do both test and test2 have same size? If they do, you should pass test2 to ChildComp  as a prop. Then use index in map to pass each item of test to onClick function. Try this:
{test2.map((data, index) => (
        <button onClick={() => onClick(test[index])}>{data}</button>
      ))}

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
const MainComp = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(' ')

  const test = [
      'One',
      'Two',
      'Three',
  ]

  return (
      <>
        {test.map(oneTest => <ChildComp data={oneTest} handleUpdateText={value => setText(value)}/>)}
      </>
  )
}

const ChildComp = ({ data, handleUpdateText }) => {
  return (
      <>
          <button onClick={handleUpdateText}>
              {data}
          </button>
      </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to use the props the send the data from Main to the Child page..??You can do it as follows:

Main Page Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Child from './Child'

const Main = ()=>{

const data = ["one","two","three"];

    return(
        <div>
        <Child data={data}/>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Child Page code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Child =({data})=>{

    const getData=()=>{
        console.log(data)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            <button onClick={getData}>Transfer Data</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Child;
```

This way, when you click on the button the data from the Main page is transfered to the Child Page. Right now the data is showing in the console..but hey, you got the data from another page and now you can do whatever you want to do with that..!!